# I have those problems after a change

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio-code, expo, runtime-error

> ****ERROR 11:12 Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/  • Field:
> android.config - should NOT have additional property 'permissions'.
> ERROR 11:12 Error: Problems validating asset fields in app.json. Learn
> more: https://docs.expo.dev/  • Field:
> android.adaptiveIcon.foregroundImage - cannot access file at
> './assets/adaptive-icon.png'.****

Errors ------->

```
11:12 Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. 
Learn more: docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration • Field:   android.config - should NOT 
have additional property 'permissions'. ERROR 11:12 Error: Problems validating asset fields in app.json. Learn more: docs.expo.dev • Field: android.adaptiveIcon.foregroundImage - cannot access file at './assets/adaptive-icon.png'.
```

Here is my code:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "cracash",
    "slug": "cracash",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.cracash",
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "hidden"
      },
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },

    "package":"com.cracash", 
    "config" :{
      "googleMaps":{
        "apiKey":"hidden"
      },

     "permissions":["ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION","ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION","FOREGROUND_SERVICE"]
    }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, please give some more clarification! What did you do to make this happen? Can you try to elaborate on your problem except for just adding a buncha error codes and whatever {"expo":{"name":"cracash",... means? We're here to help but you gotta do your part too!

Comment: do u have a discord?? or u want me to send from here

Comment: Send them here so the community can see them too!

Comment: everything was fine untill i add the changes to app.json ios Bundleidentifire add Api and project name and android config ! when i start to sets expo start it came up error and

Comment: those are the Errors -------
11:12
Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/
 • Field: android.config - should NOT have additional property 'permissions'.
ERROR
11:12
Error: Problems validating asset fields in app.json. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/
 • Field: android.adaptiveIcon.foregroundImage - cannot access file at './assets/adaptive-icon.png'.---------

Comment: Are the asset paths the same for iOS and Android configs?

Comment: Are you missing a } on  the android adaptive icon config. It is: `"adaptiveIcon": {...},...{...{...},`

Comment: Is all your code correct? I found some code at https://blog.tgxn.net/expo-adaptive-app-icon/ that may help

Comment: I think I deleted the adaptiveIcon from assets folder because I couldn’t find the and png called adaptiveicon

Comment: you should probably try restoring the adaptiveIcon to the assets folder

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue with your AdaptiveIcon. `Field: android.adaptiveIcon.foregroundImage - cannot access file at './assets/adaptive-icon.png'.` And at `Problems validating asset fields in app.json`

In summary, the error log is trying to tell you that something is wrong with adaptive-icon.png. Make sure that the path is correct in app.json's asset fields. The log is telling you everything you need to know.